# How to turn off PS4 notifications for a game that I uninstalled years ago?

Tags: ps4

A few years ago, I bought a PS4 game (*The Elder Scrolls Online*). I played it for a year and I have since uninstalled it. I did this last action around one year and a half ago.

For a few months now, I keep receiving PS4 notifications to try and put me back in the game. Just today I opened my PS4 to be greeted with a "come back and get this special mount" notification.

How can I turn those pesking notifications from that one single game that I have deleted for such a long time?

I don't want to totally get rid of the game as I might return in the future, but I don't want to always be reminded of that one game.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately, unlike say an iPhone or an Android phone, you're not able to disable notifications for a single game. However, you can disable notifications for all games in your settings. Go to Settings and then Notifications, then disable the "game alerts" notification setting. That should disable all game alerts.

---

If the above doesn't work, you might be able to fix it by unlinking your PS4 account from your ESO account. Log into https://account.elderscrollsonline.com/login and click on "linked accounts", then follow the instructions from that point on. According to the site, an unlinked account can later be linked again with no loss of progress.

Comment: This seems good enough for my preferences (why should a game provide notifications at all?) but not for people coming to the exact question. I accept it as is. If in the future my specific request is implemented by PlayStation and another answer becomes better, I'll switch the accept mark to that one.

Comment: Hello, I'm sorry I have to withdraw my checked mark: today i received a new notification from that game, inviting me to come back in the game. Your solution is unfortunately not working.

Comment: @OlivierGrégoire Okay, the only things I can think of then is that it's either a setting in the game itself (so you'll have to reinstall it) or a setting on your ESO account. I'm not sure which though. Let me check my own ESO account to see if I can find something.

Comment: @OlivierGrégoire I've given an updated suggestion on what might fix it.

Comment: Well, you get the accepted mark again. Hopefully it'll work this time. ;-)